# Echo is failing to print "*.*" string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I needed to fetch first block in "*.*" string (i.e '*') in shell script. I found that instead of printing the string it is displaying list of all file in current directory.

How overcome this issue?

main purpose is change string  "asterisk.asterick" (this read from /etc/rsyslog.conf)  to "*.debug", here first field i need keep as it is, only second field needs to change.

```
root@xyz-node:/tmp# ccvv=*.*
root@xyz-node:/tmp# echo ccvv
ccvv
root@xyz-node:/tmp# echo $ccvv
new_script.sh rsyslog.conf rsyslog.confe tmp.8R7bE0tYbg
root@xyz-node:/tmp#
root@xyz-node:/tmp#
root@xyz-node:/tmp# echo $ccvv|cut -d "." -f1
new_script
```

Comment: Add quotes to variable. bash-3.2$ echo "$ccvv" | cut -d "." -f1*

Answer (score 3):

Actually you have to quote variable itself. 
`echo "$ccvv"`

Answer (score 1):

As i understand it...

```
$ echo "*.*"
*.*

$ ccvv="*.*"

$ echo $ccvv
*.*
```

Or?

Comment: Actually, no. It seems that you get the correct answer, but that's because you have no files matching the glob `*.*` in your current directory. Try `touch test.gniourf` to create such a file, and then `ccvv="*.*"; echo $ccvv` and you'll see how the pattern was matched. To expand the variable without globbing, you must quote the variable expansion: `echo "$ccvv"`.

Comment: Actually, it depends on shell you use. In case of bash it will be matched, in case of zsh it won't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed`'s substitution:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9*]\+\.\).*/\1debug/g' InputFile
```

Here `.bak` will create a backup file named `InputFile.bak` before doing the replacement.

Example input:

```
some text
*.conf
some text
some.text
```

Output:

```
some text
*.debug
some text
some.debug
```